# my keras cannot load a model. "Invalid input_shape argument" Error message

Tags: python, keras

I want to load a model I trained before.

my code is as bellows.

```py
top3_acc = functools.partial(tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy, k=3)
top3_acc.__name__ = 'top3_acc'

modelName = "/root/workspace/cc_classifier/generatedModels/whole_model.pb"
sdi_model = keras.models.load_model(modelName, custom_objects={'top3_acc': top3_acc})
```

then, my keras return a error message like as bellows.

```py
File "/root/workspace/cc_classifier/scripts/tester/modeltester.py", line 28, in <module>
sdi_model = keras.models.load_model(modelName, custom_objects={'top3_acc': top3_acc})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
  return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 584, in load_model
 model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 274, in _deserialize_model
      model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 627, in model_from_config
      return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
      printable_module_name='layer')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
      list(custom_objects.items())))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1075, in from_config
      process_node(layer, node_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1025, in process_node
      layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 506, in __call__
      output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 612, in compute_output_shape
      str(len(self._input_layers)) + ' tensor inputs.')
    ValueError: Invalid input_shape argument [(None, 1500), (None, 400)]: model has 1 tensor inputs.
```

I don't know the reason. 
How can I fix it?

### add

I trained my model with multi-gpu option.

```
model = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=[0,1,2,3])
```

This option can make this error?

Comment: looks like `top3_acc` does not have the proper shape for `modelName`. Would it be possible for you to print the *shape* of `top3_acc`. Isn't the detected `[(None, 1500), (None, 400)]` supposed to be `(400,1500)` or something of this vein?

Comment: Are you running this code as root? That is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @MatiasValdenegro, but I use a scale container for only this task. In physical server, I run my code with low power account.

Comment: @zar3bski with this line "print (top3_acc.shape())", I've got a mesage,  "AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'shape'". How can I print that?

Comment: my bad, `custom_objects` accepts functions

Comment: Still its  bad idea, anyways, did you train this model using tf.keras?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro no, just keras. So I modified my code like, "top3_acc = functools.partial(keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy, k=3)". But still I've got a same message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. It was my fault.

I designed two input layers, syllable and morpheme.

```
cnnModelInput = keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.lexicalMaxLength,), name="syllable_input")
posModelInput = keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.morphemeMaxLength,), name="morphemePos_input")

inputFormat = [cnnModelInput, posModelInput]
```

I input "cnnModelInput" in the position of "posMudelInput"

In spec, this model has two input layers, but the model never used "posModelInput".

So that error message was emerged.

Thank you!!